# Service not working correctly

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

I am trying to learn services and background threads that can update UI, here, this service is started by calling `startService()` method from `MainActivity`, the problem is: when the loop runs for a **larger value of** `i`, Toasts are not shown for all of the values (interestingly Toast made after the loop also not showing ), but this time I tested with 10/20 etc and working perfectly.

Here are codes, of `MyService.java`:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    Handler mhandler;

    public MyService() {
        super("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Starting!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onCreate();

        mhandler = new Handler();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {


        mhandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "i is: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "finally i is: "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

And request for some really helpful resources for very beginner on Android Services, Background Tasks, Broadcast receiver. I got developer.android.com (Not too.. helpful for beginner), www.vogella.com, etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first instinct says that you are overloading the Toast. (I could be wrong). Try using `Log.v("MY_SERVICE", "i is: "+ String.valueOf(i))` instead. To see if the code works, run it and check the logcat

Comment: :) all values are shown in the log cat! but why not in the toast!?

Comment: Toast is NOT reliable for debugging purposes.

Comment: I guess I'll go ahead and post answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason you are only seeing the first few values of i is because android will not allow an application to spam the toast queue.

As mentioned by @David Wasser in the OP post's comments, Toast is not a reliable debugging tool.
Use the logcat instead:

```
Log.v("TAG", "Message")
```